# Add Search for Angular ng-bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to add a search on the Angular ng-bootstrap dropdown like you could on the AngularJS version of the dropdown.

I have not been able to find any place where someone has successfully created a search on the dropdown.

Comment: Did you try to do it yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 element `datalist` and bind it ngmodel so that you can track whats being selected.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-example',
  template: `
    <h2>Datalist and Select Example</h2>
    <label for="datalistInput">Choose a fruit (or type your own):</label>
    <input list="fruits" id="datalistInput" [(ngModel)]="selectedDatalistFruit" (input)="onDatalistChange()" />
    <datalist id="fruits">
      <option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit">{{ fruit }}</option>
    </datalist>
    <p>Selected fruit using datalist: {{ selectedDatalistFruit }}</p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  fruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grapes', 'Mango'];
  selectedDatalistFruit: string = '';
  selectedSelectFruit: string = '';

  onDatalistChange() {
    console.log('Selected fruit using datalist:', this.selectedDatalistFruit);
  }
}
```